# AWS alarm for real time values

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

(AWS Beginner)

I am connected to temperature sensors and want to trigger an email notification when temperature crosses the threshold value.

In SNS alarms,metrics are predefined and  I am not able to customize my real time alarm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon CloudWatch supports custom CloudWatch metrics.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/publishingMetrics.html

Once you have your metrics being pushed to CloudWatch, you can then create a CloudWatch alarm on your custom metrics to trigger alerts via SNS.